# Visual Studio IntelliCode Whole line completion: Is there a hotkey to trigger/force a suggestion to appear?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

I am referring to [this visual studio feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/visual-studio-whole-line-completions).

Is there a way to trigger or force a whole line suggestion to appear?
It seems very sporadic at times and I would appreciate the help it offers on a more consistent basis.

I've searched the internet unsuccessfully and combing through the hotkey configurations in Visual Studio only led me to several hotkeys for the drop-down suggestions menu, which is not what I am looking for.

Thank you in advance for any helpful comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this feature was moved to another extension named "IntelliCode Completions"

Try enabling it.